# Potential conflicting grad school interview events

Tags: graduate-admissions, interview

I've applied to several programs at several different graduate schools, and if shortlisted for interview, I expect to receive invitations by the end of January and most of them hold their visit and interview event on just two weekends in Feb. I already received an invitation, but the date will have a conflict if I receive an invitation from a few schools that I actually prefer over this one. I expect to hear from those school over the next week, but I don't know if it is ok to keep them waiting for my response to interview invitation. Is this ok to respond for making arrangements a few days after receiving the invitation?

Note 1 - The event is a 2-day event, so it is not just a short interview with me, so I am worried they might not be able to rearrange a different date only for me.

Note 2 - I have already read [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34678/how-to-politely-decline-an-interview-for-a-phd-program) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15019/what-should-be-done-about-conflicting-invitations-for-graduate-school-interviews), but my question is different! It is about whether I should keep the first one waiting to avoid a potential conflict with the interview for a preferred program.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/15019/72855

Comment: @SolarMike As it is written in Note 2 (one of those "this"' is the same as the link you have given), it is not a duplicate, and for the reason I've given in Note 2.

Comment: The question of keeping either waiting is germane to the question  and is covered in the linked question ie you want to make a decision of keeping one waiting...

Comment: @SolarMike In the linked question, the person has told the school that she/he is going, but then received another invitation with an overlap, and the one she/he had made arrangements with, was the preferred one. In my question, I am asking if I should just wait without responding to the only invitation I have so far, to see if I will be invited to the one I prefer. There are two differences: 
1. I do not have two conflicting invitations at the moment, but considering not responding  
2. If I do respond, then in case of a conflict I'd have to rearrange the interview with the school I prefer.